# Cultural references related to names Lesley and Lindsay

Tags: proper-nouns, culture

> Ted: You know, I'm proud of you--Lesley.
>
> Tim: Back at you, Lindsay.

Source: The Boss Baby 2017

When the name Lesley is mentioned one character laughs and the other gets embarrassed. Clearly there are cultural references related to Lindsay and Lesley in the movie, but I do not what they are.

**Edit:**

Is it because they sound girly and yet given to boys?

**Edit 2**:

Ted:

> So that's how you wanna play it, huh. Let's see [snatches a folder tagged TEMPLETON, TIM].
>
> Templeton, Timothy. Middle name [chuckles and laughs].
>
> I'm sorry, *Lesley*.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie. Can you add a little more context?

Comment: You understand this exactly - these old Scottish surnames are Ted and Tim's middle names, and these days they are usually given to girls, not boys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the joke is that Tim has made fun of Ted for his middle name "Lindsay", which while not exactly a *girl's* name, is not a very masculine-sounding name.  Ted responds by finding out Tim's middle name is the similarly effeminate "Lesley".

As with most humor, it probably sounds a lot funnier in context.